# Why do JSP files have exclamation marks in the filename?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

If we have a file called `user!userAdd.do?userId=18282`, then how/where does the Java interpret this request?

Comment: `?` is a question mark. `!` is an exclamation mark. Now where did you spot the exclamation mark?

Comment: @adarshr, look closer, it's there: user **!** userAdd.do?userId=18282 :-)

Comment: Oh heck, yes! I didn't spot it earlier :)

Comment: AFAIK the exclamation mark has no special meaning neither in a HTTP URL, nor in a filename - it is just a plain character. Unlike the question mark, which separates the actual address from the parameters.

Comment: JSP files do not have exclamation marks in their filenames. URLs may have exclamation marks in their paths. It isn't the same thing at all.

Answer (score 5):

Your .do extention could indicate you are using struts.  The exclamation point in struts is used as follows

user!userAdd.do

user --> maps to the class mapped to that url

userAdd --> maps to the method to call in the previous class

This technique can only be used when activating DynamicMethodInvocation.

I personally always disable this for security reasons.  With this active and the previous technique a user can effectively call every public method of your class.